# Using Titlesec, titletoc, and titleps together affects the command \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, titlesec, polyglossia, titletoc, titleps

Writing a book of probability in arabic,  I want to use the `titleps` package for different beautiful headpages, in my files where I use `titletoc` for partial table of contents. All was good until I used the package `titleps` together with `titlesec` and `titletoc`. When I put the command `\tableofcontents`, the compilation does not end, but appears to go into an infinite loop... I have tried to use `titlesec` and `titletoc`, and obtain the contents with `\tableofcontents`, and all worked well, but not when using all three packages. Why does this happen? How can I write the contents and the partial contents at the same time, and use at the same time `titleps`?

Here is a WME, used with Texmaker on Windows 8.1, where I replaced the arabic names by latin names, to watch the effect of compilation. Don't be concerned about right-to-left text, because of the main language which is arabic here, a right-to-left language...

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titleps}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Chaptername}}
\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}}

\begin{document}

\titlecontents{lsection}
  [2.3em]{\small}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {}
\titlecontents{lsubsection}
  [4.6em]{\small}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {}


\newpagestyle{Mystyle}{
  \setheadrule{.1pt}% Header rule
  \sethead[\thepage\hspace*{14pt}
    Titlebook]% even left
    []% even centre
    [\sectiontitle \hspace*{5pt} .\thesection]% even right
    {}% odd left
    {}% odd centre
    {\chaptertitle
    \hspace*{14pt}
    \thepage}% odd right
}  

\pagestyle{Mystyle}


%  \tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\startcontents[chapters]
{\large\bf Minicontents}
\vspace*{5pt}
\hrule \vspace*{-10pt} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \printcontents[chapters]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{-5pt} \hrule

\section{Section 1}
\section{Section 2}
\newpage
\section{Section 3}
\section{Section 4}

\end{document}
```

The compilation gives this pdf file, and when I uncomment `%  \tableofcontents`, the compilation never stops. I just want to put the command `\tableofcontents` at the beginning of the file !
[image][image]

I've tried to go down a level in the contents, by transforming chapter in section, and section in subsection, and now all is good ! There's no problem of compilation, it gives the contents, partial contents and uses the titleps package...
    But I need of course to go up by a level, because there is chapters in my book !...This fact may, I think, give some ideas for programmers of Latex..
    I give the following MWE

```
\documentclass[14pt,a4paper]{extbook}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{titleps}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{0.1pt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.2,AutoFakeSlant=-0.02]{Traditional Arabic}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.5]{Traditional Arabic}

\gappto\captionsarabic{\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Contents}}

\begin{document}

\titlecontents{lsection}
  [2.3em]{\small}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {}
\titlecontents{lsubsection}
  [4.6em]{\small}{\contentslabel{2.3em}}
  {\hspace*{-2.3em}}
  {}

\newpagestyle{Mystyle}{
  \setheadrule{.1pt}% Header rule
  \sethead[\thepage\hspace*{14pt}
    Titlebook]% even left
    []% even centre
    [\sectiontitle \hspace*{5pt} .\thesection]% even right
    {}% odd left
    {}% odd centre
    {\sectiontitle
    \hspace*{14pt}
    \thepage}% odd right
}  

\pagestyle{Mystyle}

\tableofcontents

\section{section 1}
\startcontents[sections]
{\large\bf Minicontents}
\vspace*{5pt}
\hrule \vspace*{-10pt} 
\begin{multicols}{2}
  \printcontents[sections]{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}
\end{multicols}
\vspace*{-5pt} \hrule

\subsection{subsection 1}
\subsection{subsection 2}
\newpage
\subsection{subsection 3}
\subsection{subsection 4}

\end{document}
```

which gives the following output. I want the same output; but with "chapter" instead of "section"

[image]
[image]

Comment: There is an error in LTR mode, which stems from the fact that you haven't loaded the packages properly. From the first page of the [`titleps` manual](http://www.texdoc.net/pkg/titleps): _It [`titleps`] can be used without `titlesec`, but you will get most of it when used together. To load it as a separate package, use the customary `\usepackage{titleps}`, but with `titlesec` you have to load it with `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`._ I still get the infinite loop when I use `polyglossia`, but with this fix the output is correct with left-to-right languages.

Comment: At all; even if the command is shorted like \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}, what I knowed, the compilation not end. I have tried in LTR mode, by putting the main language english... with the commands  \setmainlanguage{english}
 \setotherlanguage[numerals=maghrib]{arabic}...
it have the same behaviour... so it loops infinitely with \tableofcontents...

Comment: Other thing. On a try, I saw that if the toc file contains a "chapter" entry, you can't change it, even if you change the \chapter entry by \section.. you must delete the .toc file and produce another by compilation.. This is unusual in Latex.. I never saw this !